# Create a new instance and override the class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is that I have a plugin and on that plugin I need to get a specific boolean type variable. It has 2 script, here's the script.

*RCC_SETTING : ScriptableObject*

```
// Main Controller Settings
public bool useAutomaticGear = true;
```

*RCC_CARCONTROLLERV3*

```
public bool automaticGear{get{return RCCSettings.useAutomaticGear;}}
```

Now I created my own script called

*MANUALTRANSMISSION*

```
private void Start()
{
    RCC_Settings RCCSettings = new RCC_Settings();
    RCCSettings.useAutomaticGear = false;
}
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        this.GetComponent<RCC_CarControllerV3>().currentGear += 1;
    }
}
```

What it does is that it doesn't change gear until I press the `space`. Now the problem is that all of gameobject that has a `RCC_CARCONTROLLER` script is affected. I want to something like override that so that only my player will be the one who's going for a MANUAL TRANSMISSION.

Comment: Create a flag bool in your RCC_CarControllerV3, called isPlayer, and check it in Inspector for gameobjects you need (your player in this case). And then before changing the currentGear value check it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done easily. First, create this flag bool in your `RCC_CarControllerV3` like this:

```
public bool isPlayer;
```

Then, check it on the inspector of your Player (only on it).

And then, instead of this:

```
this.GetComponent<RCC_CarControllerV3>().currentGear += 1;
```

Do this:

```
var controller = this.GetComponent<RCC_CarControllerV3>();
if(controller.isPlayer)
    controller.currentGear += 1;
```

But the weird fact here is that you mentioned that this value is changed for all your gameObjects (that has this Component). Because GetComponent will only retrieve the top-level Components of your main gameObject.

To do this, you would need to use [GameObject.GetComponentInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html). But you're not doing this...

Please, I would suggest you to edit your question and put more code. In this way, we could help you better.

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't work . I tried this also earlier before I posted it here but it still affects all of the gameobject/prefab that has this script

Comment: Then, edit your question, because without more code I couldn't help. Where are you calling `this.GetComponent<RCC_CarControllerV3>()` and what used for your ScriptableObject? You need to provide more information to allow us to help you.